# Deleting a data frame row by row's named number in R

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I understand that you can delete a row by using a negative index.

```
e <- data.frame(x=seq(1,5,1), y=seq(1,5,1))

e
  x y
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4 
5 5 5

e <- e[-3,]

e
  x y
1 1 1
2 2 2
4 4 4
5 5 5
```

But now I want to delete the row that is numbered 4.

```
e <- e[-4,]

e
  x y
1 1 1
2 2 2
4 4 4
```

It instead deleted the row that was numbered 5 (but, I guess, indexed at 4).

How can I delete the row "named" #5 even if it is in a different numbered index?

Comment: `e[rownames(e) != "4", ]` (or) for multiple entries `e[!rownames(e) %in% c("3", "4"), ]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
e[rownames(e) != "4", ]
```

(or) for multiple entries

```
e[!rownames(e) %in% c("3", "4"), ]
```